# PHP contact form returns error without any detailed information

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I am not a developer. I try to modify the existing codes using online guidelines. I was trying a similar thing on one of my organization's website. It was developed using a readymade theme in HTML5. It uses php contact form to get information through the form and then mail it. I tried to add few more fields in the existing form and it is not working now. It just returns Error and nothing else. Kindly help me fix the issue. Thanks.

```
<div id="contact" class="contact-area default-padding">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="contact-items">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 contact-forms" style="width: 100% !important;">
                        <div class="form-items bg-cover shadow dark-hard text-light" style="background-image: url(assets/img/background-plain.jpg);">
                            <h2>Connect with Us</h2>
                            
                            <form action="assets/mail/contact.php" method="POST" class="contact-form">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name*" type="text">
                                            <span class="alert-error"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" type="email">
                                            <span class="alert-error"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*" type="text">
                                            <span class="alert-error"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company/School*" type="text">
                                            <span class="alert-error"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location*" type="text">
                                            <span class="alert-error"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="plans" style="font-size: 14px;color: white;">Choose a Plan:*</label>
                                              <select id="plans" name="plans">
                                                <option value="basic">Basic</option>
                                                <option value="standard">Standard</option>
                                                <option value="professional">Professional</option>
                                              </select>
                                              <span class="alert-error"></span>                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group comments">
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Your Message*"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
                                            Send Message
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Alert Message -->
                                <div class="col-md-12 alert-notification">
                                    <div id="message" class="alert-msg"></div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Following is the php file which processes the information provided via contact form and mails it.

```
if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone     = $_POST['phone'];
$company     = $_POST['company'];
$location     = $_POST['location'];
$plans     = $_POST['plans'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error">You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error">You must enter email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error">You must enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error">Please fill all fields!</div>';
    exit();
}  
else if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error">You must enter your comments</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "example@themeforest.net";
$address = "sales@raxgbc.co.in";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'Contact Form';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name, their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>";
    echo "<h3>Email Sent Successfully.</h3>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Comment: Whats the error being returned? as I feel the question doesn't have a lot to go off of here.

Comment: You may run into problems trying to send the email _from_ the address that the person filling in your form has provided - many email servers will only send emails from domains that they are configured for.